# How do I get a series of date string out of a giant array?

Tags: javascript

Below is an array of dates in a specific time format.
I want to be able to make a new array of all the dates containing '2017-01' (All days from Jan 2017)

```
const datesArray = [
  "2017-01-01",
  "2017-01-02",
  "2017-01-03",
  "2017-01-04",
  "2017-01-05",
  "2017-01-06",
  "2017-01-07",
  "2017-01-08",
  "2017-01-09",
  "2017-01-10",
  "2017-01-11",
  "2017-01-12",
  "2017-01-13",
  "2017-01-14",
  "2017-01-15",
  "2017-01-16",
  "2017-01-17",
  "2017-01-18",
  "2017-01-19",
  "2017-01-20",
  "2017-01-21",
  "2017-01-22",
  "2017-01-23",
  "2017-01-24",
  "2017-01-25",
  "2017-01-26",
  "2017-01-27",
  "2017-01-28",
  "2017-01-29",
  "2017-01-30",
  "2017-01-31",
  "2017-02-01",
  "2017-02-02",
  "2017-02-03",
  "2017-02-04",
  "2017-02-05",
  "2017-02-06",
  "2017-02-07",
  "2017-02-08",
  "2017-02-09",
  "2017-02-10",
  "2017-02-11",
  "2017-02-12",
  "2017-02-13",
...
];
```

I have tried to work with regex but need further clarification!

Comment: `datesArray.filter(d => d.indexOf('2017-01') != -1)` would work I think

Comment: `datesArray.filter(d => d.startsWith('2017-01'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter`, and `String.slice` to get the first 7 letters to compare against.

eg.

```js
const datesArray = [
  "2017-01-01",
  "2017-01-02",
  "2017-01-03",
  "2017-01-04",
  "2017-01-05",
  "2017-01-06",
  "2017-01-07",
  "2017-01-08",
  "2017-01-09",
  "2017-01-10",
  "2017-01-11",
  "2017-01-12",
  "2017-01-13",
  "2017-01-14",
  "2017-01-15",
  "2017-01-16",
  "2017-01-17",
  "2017-01-18",
  "2017-01-19",
  "2017-01-20",
  "2017-01-21",
  "2017-01-22",
  "2017-01-23",
  "2017-01-24",
  "2017-01-25",
  "2017-01-26",
  "2017-01-27",
  "2017-01-28",
  "2017-01-29",
  "2017-01-30",
  "2017-01-31",
  "2017-02-01",
  "2017-02-02",
  "2017-02-03",
  "2017-02-04",
  "2017-02-05",
  "2017-02-06",
  "2017-02-07",
  "2017-02-08",
  "2017-02-09",
  "2017-02-10",
  "2017-02-11",
  "2017-02-12",
  "2017-02-13"
];

const f = datesArray.filter(dt => dt.slice(0, 7) === '2017-01');

console.log(f);
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured there was a vanilla method I could use! Really appreciate your help!